# Reset the reordered TableView rows on button click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am implementing a tableview which it shows a lists of documents:

[image]

MyTableviewController

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    var animalNameArray = ["cat","dog","lion"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
    }

    @IBAction func editButtonAtNavigationBar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.tableview.isEditing = !self.tableview.isEditing
        sender.title = (self.tableview.isEditing) ?  "Done" : "Edit"
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return animalNameArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let valueAtCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        valueAtCell.cellLabel?.text = animalNameArray[indexPath.row]
        return valueAtCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            animalNameArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    //Rearranging the table view cells

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let itemMove = animalNameArray[sourceIndexPath.row]
        animalNameArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        animalNameArray.insert(itemMove, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
     }
 }
```

1. I want to reset the reordered lists clicking on cancel button. How?
2. When I close the application and start it again (any time refresh data function runs), rows comes back to their default places while I need to have saved the changes in reordering. 
   [image]

And how can i use image (trash) at the position of delete??

Comment: *"I want to reset the reordered lists ,clicking on cancel button .How??"* - Have two lists, one which is sorted, one which is not, switch between them

Comment: sorry I didn't get, can you elaborate more

Comment: You don't get having one list which is sorted and one which is not and switching between them based on which list you want to use as your datasource?

Comment: Hi Laxmipriya, You can store the array in local DB or core data,  While re-ordering the values, and clicking on Done button, update the array in DB, If you cancel dont update the db, so that after you close App and reopen, fetch the data from DB..

For re-ordering purpose, As @MadProgrammer suggesting, take another array variable keep the backup of original array, then on cancel set the backup array to datasource and reload, Hope It will help you.

Comment: @janmenjaya  Sorry,I am completely new and confused what to do exactly, is it possible for you to edit my codes the way you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    var animalNameArray = [String]() {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(animalNameArray, forKey: "savedNameArray")
        }
    }
    var originalArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self
        animalNameArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "savedNameArray") as? [String] ?? ["cat","dog","lion"]
        originalArray = animalNameArray
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    @IBAction func editButtonAtNavigationBar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.tableview.isEditing = !self.tableview.isEditing
        sender.title = (self.tableview.isEditing) ?  "Done" : "Edit"
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonAtNavigationBar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.tableview.isEditing = false
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Edit"
        animalNameArray = originalArray
        tableview.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return animalNameArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let valueAtCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        valueAtCell.cellLabel?.text = animalNameArray[indexPath.row]
        return valueAtCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            animalNameArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    //Rearranging the table view cells

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let itemMove = animalNameArray[sourceIndexPath.row]
        animalNameArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        animalNameArray.insert(itemMove, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
}
```

Try this code, and connect your cancel button from storyboard to `@IBAction func cancelButtonAtNavigationBar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)`

Comment: one more thing how can i use image at the position of delete

Comment: Please open another question for new question.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    var animalNameArray = ["cat","dog","lion"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource = self

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let operationArray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringArray") ?? [String]()
        if operationArray.count == 0 {
        }else{
            animalNameArray = operationArray
        }

    }

    @IBAction func editButtonAtNavigationBar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.tableview.isEditing = !self.tableview.isEditing
        sender.title = (self.tableview.isEditing) ?  "Done" : "Edit"
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return animalNameArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let valueAtCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        valueAtCell.cellLabel?.text = animalNameArray[indexPath.row]
        return valueAtCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            animalNameArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            print(animalNameArray)

            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(animalNameArray, forKey: "SavedStringArray")

        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    //Rearranging the table view cells

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let itemMove = animalNameArray[sourceIndexPath.row]
        animalNameArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        animalNameArray.insert(itemMove, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

        print(animalNameArray)
    }


}
```

Download sample

https://github.com/testingraahul/TableViewEditing/tree/master